# Increment dataframe column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to create a new column based on a condition on a different column. Create the new column "ans" with 1 and increment based on the column "ix". In the "ix" column if the value is the same as the next one keep the "ans" column the same and if its different increment "ans"

Thank you for your answer, I am new to Python so I am not sure how to do this

```
      index   ix  
        1     pa 
        2     pa
        3     pa
        4     pe
        5     fc
        6     pb
        7     pb
        8     df
```

should result in:-

```
      index   ix  ans
        1     pa   1
        2     pa   1
        3     pa   1
        4     pe   2
        5     fc   3
        6     pb   4
        7     pb   4
        8     df   5
```

Comment: Sorry mistake, I have edited the question

Comment: does it have to be by order of appearance in `ix`? or just give each value a unique incrementing num?

Comment: Yes by order it appears in ix

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
In [47]: df['ans'] = (df['ix'] != df['ix'].shift(1)).cumsum()

In [48]: df
Out[48]: 
   index  ix  ans
0      1  pa    1
1      2  pa    1
2      3  pa    1
3      4  pe    2
4      5  fc    3
5      6  pb    4
6      7  pb    4
7      8  df    5
```